# Uwp attached property not firing a property changed callback

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a custom attached property defined:

```
 public static IList<Object> GetBindings(DependencyObject obj)
 {
    return (IList<Object>)obj.GetValue(BindingsProperty);
 }

 public static void SetBindings(DependencyObject obj, IList<Object> value)
 {
    obj.SetValue(BindingsProperty, value);
 }

 // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Bindings.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
 public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Bindings", typeof(IList<Object>), typeof(KeyboardInput), new PropertyMetadata(new List<Object>(), OnBindingsChanged));


 private static void OnBindingsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     Debugger.Break();
 }
```

Xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox" 
         PlaceholderText="Add a comment...">

    <app:KeyboardInput.Bindings> 
      <app:KeyBinding />
    </app:KeyboardInput.Bindings>

</TextBox>
```

And method, which listens to the property changes (`OnBindingsChanged`). Why it isn't firing when the default value (`new List<object>()`) is assigned to a property? What is the way to access a target object after it was already contructed in xaml?

Comment: dont ever change the binding to a new object it breaks the exisiting binding.  It is better to clear the list than create a new one.

Comment: So i should just leave null instead?

Comment: I would not bind to null.  Use an empty ObservableCollection

Comment: I've used an ObservableCollection , but the property changed callback still doesn't fire

Comment: I have tested your code and the property changed callback `OnBindingsChanged` did fire. I am calling `KeyboardInput.SetBindings(MyGrid, new List<object>());`. Could you specify how exactly are you calling the method?

Comment: I'm not really calling a method, but set a property value from xaml:

Comment: @AndriyShevchenko: What is app:KeyBinding?

Comment: It's a DependencyObject, i hope it's added to a `Bindings` collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event won't fire because you have given the property a default value of `new List<object>` so in XAML when you set the binding like:

```
<app:KeyboardInput.Bindings> 
      <app:KeyBinding />
</app:KeyboardInput.Bindings>
```

you are simply just adding an item to the existing list which doesn't change the actual value of the property.
I recommend replacing it with an ObservableCollection and then listening to the CollectionChanged event which will fire every time an item is added or removed.